# Finding minimum value between 2 numbers without comparision operators

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I have seen the following method which gives the minimum value b/w 2 numbers without relational operators

```
y + ((x - y) & ((x - y) >>(sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1)))
```

In here if x=6 and y=4 x-y=2 is positive and shifting this value 31 times to the right gives 0.(as sign bit is 0 for +ve numbers) and the eqn becomes

```
y + ((x-y)&0)
```

From the above eqn we get y as min value which is true.

But for the case where x=4 and y=6, x-y=-2 and shifting it 31 times to right gives 1 and the eqn becomes:

```
y + ((x-y)&1)
```

As per my understanding bitwise & of -2 and 1 becomes 0 and the eqn gives o/p as y(6) instead of x(4). Can someone explain?

Full code: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compute-the-minimum-or-maximum-max-of-two-integers-without-branching/

Thanks

Comment: The link says: "If we know that `INT_MIN <= (x - y) <= INT_MAX`" so it is restricting the set of numbers on which it will work. Suppose (32-bit `int`) that `x = -2000000000` and `y = 2000000000` the subtraction will cause an overflow. The article goes on to say "Typically, the obvious approach is best, though."

Comment: "...becomes `y + ((x-y)&1)`" this is not correct. It becomes `& 1....1b` (32 binary ones), and `z & 1...1b = z` for any `z`.

Comment: @Evg how does shifting -2 by 31 bits give us 1...1b. Can you explain?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude GCC9.1, Xeon  E3, -std=c++11, `int x = -2; x = x >> 31;` results in -1.

Comment: Actually here is some play with implyed type casting, I think, because regardless that  `(y + ((x - y) & ((x - y) >>(sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1))))` works on same platform.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Looks like [compiler optimizes it](https://godbolt.org/z/4rP8D1)

Comment: @KamilCuk. yes, because of implied promotions it can do that, and typeid(sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1) shows that type of the expression is `unsigned long`. SUpposedly in that implementation, the macro is a  `unsigned long` literal. That code isn't x64 one though , but looks better than code offered in answer below.One of examples where switching instruction set isn't BEST way to increase performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The explanation given on the said website is wrong. When `x < y`

```
(x - y) >> 31 = 0b1...1 (32 ones) (*)
```

And then

```
y + ((x - y) & 0b1...1) = y + (x - y) = x
```

(*) Note that the right shift of a negative number is implementation-defined. Typically, it performs an [arithmetic right shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift), filling all binary digits with the most significant one which is `1` for a negative number in two's complement representation.

Comment: Finally, someone who speaks English :)

Comment: Tony Stark to Banner, quote :P

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie, теперь понял. :)

Comment: Thank you! It was not easy to find out about right shift of negative numbers.

Answer (score 2):

It is not efficient and slower on many architectures than the "normal" way. I should also mention that it is not readable and very error prone.

example:

```
int foo(int x, int y) 
{
    return (y + ((x - y) & ((x - y) >>(sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1))));
}

int foo1(int x, int y) 
{
    return x > y ? y : x;
}
```

and the resulting code (ARM Cortex):

```
foo:
        sub     r0, r0, r1
        and     r0, r0, r0, asr #31
        add     r0, r0, r1
        bx      lr
foo1:
        cmp     r0, r1
        movge   r0, r1
        bx      lr
```

or x86

```
foo:
        sub     edi, esi
        mov     eax, edi
        sar     eax, 31
        and     eax, edi
        add     eax, esi
        ret
foo1:
        cmp     edi, esi
        mov     eax, esi
        cmovle  eax, edi
        ret
```

Comment: not sure how assembler code alone can show it as "slower", because it should be profiles as part of actual target code.  foo doesn't generate branch, but can we benefit from branch trimming or not is point of profiling, not of reading instructions.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie both do not generate branches. And both use simple low cycle instructions. "Traditional" in both cases are smaller and faster.

Answer (score 2):

Until new standard would be approved the representation of signed integers is implementation-based, and >> on them as well ( << is an UB). Let assume that   platform got signed values as complements of 2, then -2 in binary is 11111111111111111111111111111110. Shifting it to right 31 times may actually result in value of all bits set (which equals to -1) or in value 1, depends on implementation. It should be `static_cast` to unsigned to be shifted in definite way.